# How to get sound woking in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I hope you are having a good day. Today on 30/08/2022 I sat down to work on my game in unity 2021.3.6f1 on my ubuntu 20.04 computer and all the audio was on playing I made new sound tracks but, the sound tracks still didn't play at all. If anyone knows how to fix it plz help.

The sound manager code I use is:

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class AudioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sound[] sounds;

    private void Awake() {
        foreach (Sound s in sounds) {
            s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();

            s.source.clip = s.clip;

            s.source.volume = s.volume;
            s.source.pitch = s.pitch;

            s.source.loop = s.loop;
        }
    }

    public void Play(string name) {
        Sound soundToPlay = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
        soundToPlay.source.Play();
    }
}
```

The "Sound" class code:

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

[System.Serializable]
public class Sound {
    public string name;
    public AudioClip clip;

    [Range(0f, 1f)]
    public float volume = 1f;

    [Range(1f, 3f)]
    public float pitch = 1f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public AudioSource source;

    public bool loop = false;
}
```

Comment: When you add sounds to the audio manager what happens?

Comment: It doesn't display any errors or warnings it just doesn't play any sounds.

Comment: So you are able to add sounds to the audio manager? The code you specify doesn't add any sounds to play, so there wouldn't be anything to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the Audio Icon is not clicked. And make sure that this is not getting set to off when the game is running. If all the code is working, I would guess its this.

[image: UnityAudioIconTop]